# Cloudera Manager inspector not running on hosts

Tags: linux, hadoop, cloudera

I currently have 3 machines, all bootcamped macs running Ubuntu, and am trying to set them up as a Hadoop cluster using CDH 5. While using the installer wizard, when it 'inspects the hosts for correctness I get the errors shown below.

[image]

The inspector fails on all hosts and it says

```
IOException thrown while collecting data from host: Connection refused
```

While setting up the machines the only thing I did before running the cloudera manager installer was enable ssh.

In the hosts file all have localhost and my user on 127.0.0.1

Any ideas on why the connection was refused orhat I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend assigning static IP addressees to all 3 machines. After that, make sure your /etc/hosts file does not map your hostname to 127.0.1.1 as Ubuntu often does by default (just localhost should be bound to 127.0.1.1). Finally, verify that you can ping all the machines from each other.